# How to send all subdomains of my domain to the same server using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain

I have a domain in AWS like example.com
But I want all requests of the subdomains, rea.example.com, exem2.example.com be sent to the same server.

For now I've created Record Set like *.example.com and it does not work.
When I set the subdomain as a new "record set" it works, but I need to answer to all subdomains, that are created dinamically by the application.

Thanks

Comment: where is your dns? route53 or somewhere else?

Comment: Good question, because in Route53, that *does* work.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan Route 53

Answer (score -1):

Now is fixed. It was a missing configuration in the etc/httpd/httpd.conf. To allow all requests and resources be answered by the server.

In the httpd.conf was added:

## Custom htaccess file

AccessFileName .htaccess

And was created another file in the folder:
etc/httpd/conf.d/
mydomain.conf

with the virtual hosts:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ```
>
> ## ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"

    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/folder_app

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>


    <Directory /var/www/folder_app>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Comment: you didn't provide any information in your question to indicate what http server you were using, but in any case, consider including the config that helped you fix the problem so it can help others who see this question.